# Multiple Date Argument Values with One Contextual Filter

Tags: 7, datetime, views

I have a pretty simple view in D7:

**Fields**

- nid
- title

**Contextual Filters**

- nid
- date (from date, monthly granularity)

Now I'd like to fetch some results for a specific node, but across multiple months. I was hoping to be able to pass in the contextual filter arguments via the url like so:

```
123/201302+201303
```

This isn't working for me though. Is this even possible with Date fields in Views ? I heard it was only possible with term ids right now.

Are there other techniques to accomplish this? Perhaps hook_views_query_alter() is in order here.

Comment: did you try views_embed_view('viewname', 'display_name', array(123,'201302+201303'))?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about views_embed_view, I will give that a try next time. For now, I ended up just going with a hook_views_query_alter and modifying the where condition to span across both months. I did this because I am using Panels to place the view on the page, and didn't want to render the view via code.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following method using `views_embed_view()`:

```
views_embed_view('viewname', 'display_name', array(123,'201302+201303'));
```

Or by using a `hook_views_query_alter` and modifying the where condition to span across both months.